# How to edit a LWC meta file in developer console?

Tags: lightning-web-components, developer-console

I am able to edit Aura components in developer console. However I want to edit some files in LWC components also like the js-meta.xml but I am unable to find those components under lightning resources.

Is there a way?

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot as noted in the [LWC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc).

> Develop Lightning web components with a workflow that fits your needs.
> We recommend Salesforce DX tools, but you might be in a situation
> where those tools are not supported. You can still use your favorite
> code editor and deploy to an org using your own tools. **However, you
> can’t develop Lightning web components in the Developer Console**.

[Setting up your development environment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.install_setup_develop) goes over how you can edit it, but also reiterates that you cannot develop in Developer Console.

Comment: ok thank you. Yeah it was a short tweak I wanted to do to see on my local sandbox. But I will just deploy it.